# Artisan migrate fails in development environment because of missing environment variable in production config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate, laravel-migrations

I have two database configs, one for production and one for development:

```
// app/config/database.php
'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'database'  => $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'username'  => $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'password'  => $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )
)

// app/config/development/database.php
'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_SERVER['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'],
        'database'  => $_SERVER['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE'],
        'username'  => $_SERVER['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER'],
        'password'  => $_SERVER['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )
)
```

The relevant database environment variables exist (the ones beginning with `MYSQL_`), and when running the migrate command:

```
php artisan migrate --env=development
```

the following exception gets thrown:

```
{
    "error":{
        "type":"ErrorException",
        "message":"Undefined index: RDS_HOSTNAME",
        "file":"/var/www/app/config/database.php",
        "line":50
    }
}
```

Why does Laravel care if the environment variable in my production config doesn't exist when I don't even want to use the production configuration? How do I get around this?

Comment: Possibly because it's PHP warning which is handled by Laravel and it treats warnings as errors.

Comment: Does the App::environment(); output "development" ?

Comment: Yeah, but why would Laravel even be executing the production config when I specified the development environment? Is there a way to get Laravel to ignore warnings such as this?

Comment: @Th3Alchemist Yeah, putting `die(var_dump(App::environment()));` at the top of the file causes it to print `development`.

Comment: What Laravel version do you run? could you check your /bootstrap/start.php (for 4.2) and check if your hostname is registered as development envirnoment?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can happen when in your `.env` file you have the following

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Instead, you should have

```
RDS_CONNECTION=mysql
RDS_HOSTNAME=localhost
RDS_PORT=3306
RDS_DB_NAME=test_db
RDS_USERNAME=root
RDS_PASSWORD=
```

The difference is in the name of the keys. In addition to that, [this might be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482050/5675325) in case that problem is related with bash and AWS.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use environment variables instead, and make sure the keys match between environments (I think that's your biggest issue).

```
// File: .env.development.php
return [
    'database_mysql_host' => '',
    'database_mysql_database' => '',
    'database_mysql_username' => '',
    'database_mysql_password' => '',
];
```

Then you can remove both of your config files and just modify `app/config/database.php`:

```
'connections' => array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_ENV['database_mysql_host'],
        'database'  => $_ENV['database_mysql_database'],
        'username'  => $_ENV['database_mysql_username'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['database_mysql_password'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )
)
```

I'm assuming for the moment that you're setting the environment variables on the production server in the vhost or some other apache configuration file.  Change those keys where they are being set from the 'special' ones you picked out for your production environment to match the keys you're using in your development environment:

```
SetEnv database_mysql_host {your value for RDS_HOSTNAME}
SetEnv database_mysql_database {your value for RDS_DB_NAME}
SetEnv database_mysql_username {your value for RDS_USERNAME}
SetEnv database_mysql_password {your value for RDS_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: Not an option unfortunately. Docker automatically sets the development variables and it would be a PITA to change them. The RDS variables are set by Amazon Web Services.

Comment: an alternate solution could be to just make sure that both sets of environment config keys are at least available (even if empty) in both environments