# "Database hosts array is empty." after deploying Laravel project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my project to an AWS EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk. I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISVaMijczKc) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISVaMijczKc as a reference while deploying. I am following everything as it is in the tutorial but I ended up with an error.

> Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select * from
>   `resource_categories`)

The following are my codes.

**database.php**

```
<?php

define('RDS_HOSTNAME', $_SERVER['RED_HOSTNAME']);
define('RDS_USERNAME', $_SERVER['RED_USERNAME']);
define('RDS_PASSWORD', $_SERVER['RED_PASSWORD']);
define('RDS_DB_NAME', $_SERVER['RED_DB_NAME']);

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => RDS_HOSTNAME,
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => RDS_DB_NAME,
            'username' => RDS_USERNAME,
            'password' => RDS_PASSWORD,
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],

];
```

***.ENV***

```
APP_NAME="MyProject"
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=base64:FlVBd61BUEzVx6ACa6OOn3Jrp4z+VRpug+F1K1ZeJOs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: you have to set the environment variable from the elastic beanstalk environment

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz Thanks for your input, I'd really appreciate it if you could elaborate or walk me through. I'm new to these. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone through a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65481464/5675325) and MarkB helped me. There's a specific procedure you must follow when you SSH into the instance.

If you run

```
export
```

you can see that there's no variable named RDS_HOSTNAME in that Linux shell and that's why you're getting that error.

If you run

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

you can see an object with the list of properties, including that RDS_HOSTNAME.

If you run

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_USERNAME
```

you get the value associated with that particular property. This value needs to be saved in a variable and exported so that other commands can recognize it.

If you run

```
export RDS_USERNAME="value"
```

then when you run

```
export
```

you can see that this is now available.

Now if you run the command you wanted it's likely gonna work (you might need to repeat this for RDS_USERNAME, RDS_PASSWORD and RDS_DB_NAME).

*Note*: if that didn't work, then your problem might be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960016/5675325).

Answer (score 1):

[This is a bug report which might be related to this problem.](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/issues/1022) The long and the short is that if the ConnectionFactory gets passed a `NULL` value it will (erroneously) trigger that error. I suspect that all of your RDS variables are empty.

To set these values, [you can follow instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html).

Comment: It's still a configuration issue. I suggest you try to find where the string `Database hosts array is empty.` comes up. You can then work backwards from there.