# AWS EB undefined RDS_HOSTNAME with Database hosts array empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

Currently in a Laravel project using AWS EB with RDS.

When I run

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

then I get

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RDS_HOSTNAME in /var/app/current/config/database.php on line 5
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RDS_USERNAME in /var/app/current/config/database.php on line 6
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RDS_PASSWORD in /var/app/current/config/database.php on line 7
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RDS_DB_NAME in /var/app/current/config/database.php on line 8

and

> Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select * from
> information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name =
> migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

[image: php artisan migrate --seed]

I'm not using a .env file but defining these variables in EB configuration, like

[image]

and my ./config/database.php file

[image]

[image]

Tested changing the variables' prefix to RDS_ instead of DB_ in EB but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Elastic Beanstalk documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pass-variables/):

> **Note**: Environment properties aren't automatically exported to the
> shell, even though they are present in the instance. Instead,
> environment properties are made available to the application through
> the stack that it runs in, based on which platform you're using.

So Elastic Beanstalk is going to pass those environment variables to the Apache HTTP server process, but not the Linux shell where you are running that `php` command.

Per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-accessing), you need to use the [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html) script to pull those environment variable values into your shell.

So you'll need to do this for all

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_USERNAME
```

which will print the value of RDS_USERNAME. Then export it to use in other commands

```
export RDS_USERNAME="value"
```

Do that for all - RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_USERNAME, RDS_PASSWORD and RDS_DB_NAME. Then if you run

```
export
```

you must be able to see RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_USERNAME, RDS_PASSWORD and RDS_DB_NAME and the respective value in front.

Once that's done and you run

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

you'll then get as expected

[image]

Comment: Mark B if I run `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` I can see the object with the list of properties and running `php artisan migrate --seed` still gets me to the same error as before. I've seen people doing this operation before by creating a .ebextensions folder in the root of their app and have there this command (which once is run then needs to be deleted - so ideally I'd be able to run without that folder)

Comment: I just tested that way with the .ebextensions folder (as [explained here](https://youtu.be/ISVaMijczKc)) but the instance then got into a degraded state. So ideally I'd SSH into the instance and run the command when needed.

Comment: Just running `get-config` does nothing but print the values to the console. You still need to set them in an environment variable in your shell.

Comment: MarkB if I run in the shell `echo $RDS_HOSTNAME"` (or, instead of HOSTNAME - USERNAME, PASSWORD and DB_NAME) then I'm able to see each of the respective values. Yet, when I run the command, now it says that what is undefined is `RDS_PASSWORD` and `RDS_DB_NAME`.

Comment: If I run `export` i don't see `RDS_PASSWORD` and `RDS_DB_NAME` in it.

Comment: Oh wait I do see their values.